# How to avoid code duplication in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

```
public static void sendMail(String[] to, String subject, String messageBody, String[] cc, String[] bcc) throws Exception {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, fromname));
    InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
        toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);    
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
    }
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(messageBody, "text/html");
    if(cc[0] != "") {
        InternetAddress[] ccAddress = new InternetAddress[cc.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
            ccAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(cc[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ccAddress.length; i++) {
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAddress[i]);
        }
    }
    if(bcc[0] != "") {
        InternetAddress[] bccAddress = new InternetAddress[bcc.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < bcc.length; i++) {
            bccAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(bcc[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bccAddress.length; i++) {
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddress[i]);
        }
    }
    Transport transport = session.getTransport();
    try {
        System.out.println("Sending...");
        transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        System.out.println("Email sent!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
        System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        transport.close();
    }
}
public static void sendMail(String[] to, String subject, String messageBody) throws Exception {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, fromname));
    InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
        toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
    }
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(messageBody, "text/html");
    Transport transport = session.getTransport();
    try {
        System.out.println("Sending...");
        transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        System.out.println("Email sent!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
        System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

In this we are using same code in two methods.
I want to place the common code in another method.
I will try to put that common code in another method then we will trying to call that method but it doesn't work with both methods.
If we will trying to call a common method in both methods it will be applicable to only one method.

Please give me any suggestion to do this.

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Sending mail based on different strategies? May be you should take a look at `design patterns`.

Comment: maybe your second method should just call the first method like this: `sendMail(to, subject, messageBody, new String[0], new String[0]);`.

Comment: See what functionality you want to deliver, and have your common method do that. In your calling methods, then, you would need to *adapt* the data you have to the data that the common functionality is expecting. This should help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could potentially write your second method to use the first method, with empty arrays:

```
public static void sendMail(String[] to, String subject, String messageBody) throws Exception {
    sendMail(to, subject, messageBody, new String[]{""}. new String[]{""});
}
```

This passes in an empty string in the cc and bcc arrays, so that your other method will skip that array.

Note that you are leaving yourself open to NullPointerExceptions here:

```
if(cc[0] != "") { ... }
```

This is blindly assuming that the cc array contains at least one element.
If you were to call the method with an empty array, or null for cc or bcc, then your program will throw an exception.
Inside that if statement, you are already using cc.length, so if cc.length is zero, then no CC addresses will be added.
A better implementation of that test might be:

```
if (cc != null && cc.length > 0) {...}
```

Also, I am not sure why you build the ccAddress array only to discard it.
Here is the same loop, replacing the ccAddress array with a single ccAddress object.

```
if(cc != null && cc.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
        InternetAddress ccAddress = new InternetAddress(cc[i]);
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAddress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could go ahead then, and set this as answered?  By the way, if you made the change to test (cc != null) then your shorter method could then be written as   sendMail(to, subject, messageBody, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing you can do, is to implement you second method so, that it calls the first one a way, that it eill not add any cc or bcc recipients. Based on your current code it can be:

```
public static void sendMail(String[] to, String subject, String body) {
    sendMail(to, subject, body, new Object[]{""}, new Object[]{""});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to make another method. The method with the lower parameter count just calls the one with the higher parameter count with null values and you make a null check in the "real" method.

```
public static void sendMail(String[] to, String subject, String messageBody, String[] cc, String[] bcc) throws Exception {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, fromname));
    InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
        toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);    
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
    }
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(messageBody, "text/html");
    if(cc != null && cc[0] != "") {
        InternetAddress[] ccAddress = new InternetAddress[cc.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
            ccAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(cc[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ccAddress.length; i++) {
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAddress[i]);
        }
    }
    if(bcc != null && bcc[0] != "") {
        InternetAddress[] bccAddress = new InternetAddress[bcc.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < bcc.length; i++) {
            bccAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(bcc[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bccAddress.length; i++) {
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddress[i]);
        }
    }
    Transport transport = session.getTransport();
    try {
        System.out.println("Sending...");
        transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        System.out.println("Email sent!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
        System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        transport.close();
    }
}

public static void sendMail(String[] to, String subject, String messageBody) throws Exception {
    sendMail(to, subject, messageBody, null, null);
}
```